# how to improve my project on computer science department portal?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i have made a project on computer science department portal on netbeans using java. it contains a login page so that its user can login. there are three users Students,Admin,Faculty.
each of the user has its different functions like ebooks upload,download, faculty details,etc according to the user. it has the database connectivity also.
please tell how can i improve it

Comment: Well, just do it. Go on and improve it.

Comment: It'll be a much better idea to ask your users.

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt you'll get much response to this.  If you gave a link to it someone might be bored and throw some ideas out, but as stated, this isn't an answerable question.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few tips on which features you can add and how to improve the existing ones:

Regarding your account managing system and security features:

-Do you have a registration form? Are the fields checked before sending them to server? Does the server also verify this fields (Specially: are they escaped to avoid SQL injections)?

-Do you have a password recovery system?

-Do you have an email verification system?

-Do you have a contact form?

-Do you have a captcha to protect all this functions?

-Is there a function for the admin user to block/restrict or delete accounts? is it password protected?

-Do users have a public profile where they can pick which profile data to share with who (public, other users, admin users...)?

-Do you implement secure login (SSL protocol (HTTPS) on all login and password request forms, of course you need an authority to sign your certificate for authentication but even with self signing at least you can provide encryption so the data doesn't travel unencrypted on an unsecured network like an open WiFi network)

-**Very important**: Are the account passwords stored hashed?

-Is your site protected against XSS? (Meaning: Is any user/external input being properly escaped before being displayed and do you use httponly cookies?)

Regarding database access features:

-Can you perform a basic search and display the results?

-Can you filter this search results?

-Can you perform a search restricted by ranges of values on different parameters and combinations of them?

-What about the results display order?

Plus more or less the same than with the account registration/managing for any item you let the users/admins add/remove to/from the database...

That's all I can think right now, but you can get more inspiration by looking at the functions implemented by any popular webpage.

Also, this 2 sites may help you validate the HTML output and CSS code of your site:

http://validator.w3.org/

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: +1; nice answer! In general I do not upvote answers to off-topic questions, but this one is great.